# change value of property in state reducer redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer that's state is an array of objects.

```
state = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'peter',
      visible: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'alan',
      visible: false
    ];
```

The relevant part of my reducer looks like this.

`action.id` here is `1`

```
case 'TOGGLE_VIEW':

    return state.map(item => {

        if(item.id === action.id) {

            item.visible = !item.visible;

        }

    });
```

The code above returns state to be `[null, null]`

Can anyone explain how I can change the value of property in the state based on an id passed in?

Comment: Missing `return`  inside `.map`

Comment: apologies, updated!

Comment: Some typo: `name 'peter'` gorgot `:` and `{
      id: 2,
      name: 'alan',
      visible: false
    ]` forgot `}`
And Rajesh right, you don't return anything in map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on naortor's answer, since redux state should be immutable, you should do this:

```
case 'TOGGLE_VIEW':
  return state.map(item => {

    if (item.id === action.id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        visible: !item.visible,
      }
    }

    return item

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return inside the map callback function

```
case 'TOGGLE_VIEW':

return state.map(item => {

    if(item.id === action.id) {

        item.visible = !item.visible;

    }

    return item // you need a return inside your map callback function.

});
```